# Open workbook based on cell data, copy info, paste into activebook.

Tags: vba, excel

I have a value in cell **A1** that reflects a **job number**. The file I want to open is in: **G:\fixtures\ (cell a1 value)\purchase list\ (targetfile.xls)**.

Once this file is open, I want to copy cells the cells in columns A-to-G.

I then want to paste this copied data into cell **A5** in my Activesheet in the workbook: **LATHE_PROJECT_5_15_2017.xlsm** . This active sheet's name in this workbook will always change as these sheets are created when a job number entered on a previous page. So I'm a bit confused as to the **WBKDEST**. line

I'm very new to the world of excel VBA. Any guidance as to why what I'm trying to accomplish isn't working would be GREATLY appreciated.

Also: I've learned so much from this community just reading old posts. Thanks for helping dolts like me!

```
Sub import()
Dim wbkSrc As Workbook, wbkDest As Workbook
Dim myFile As String
Dim Path As String
Dim emptyRow As Long

emptyRow = 1
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set wbkDest = Workbooks("LATHE_PROJECT_5_15_2017.xlsm")
Path = "G:\FIXTURES\" & Range("A1").Value & "\purchase lists\"
myFile = Dir(Path & "*.xls??")
Set wbkSrc = Workbooks.Open(Path & myFile)
wbkSrc.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:g100").Copy
wbkDest.Worksheets.ActiveSheet.Cells(a5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
wbkSrc.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change 
"wbkDest.Worksheets.ActiveSheet.Cells(a5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues"
to
"wbkDest.ActiveSheet.Cells(a5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues"

or

"wbkDest.Worksheets(ParticularWorksheetName).Cells(a5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues"

Comment: sorry i am very new, but i could not find any comment section

Comment: Yes, it's the only .xls file in the destination. The reason I'm not putting a name there is because it's a variable name also: *jobnumber*purchaselist.xls. So instead of adding in another range, I wanted to keep it simple.

Comment: you have problem in "Worksheets.ActiveSheet." you can remove Worksheets if you are specifying activesheet. I changed that part and code is running fine.........'wbkDest.Worksheets.ActiveSheet.Cells(a5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
ThisWorkbook.Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Comment: @mrc I'm getting an error with my path. Debug is referring to this line:


'Set wbkSrc = Workbooks.Open(Path & myFile)


The error is: Runtime "error 1004"

Comment: @mrc the error 1004 says it can not access *g:\fixtures\cella1\purchase lists*

Comment: @mrc Sorry, I ran something incorrectly: It's saying it can't open the worksheet I'm aiming for because it may be 'read only' or encrypted? I put the file there myself.... there shouldn't be any encryption to prevent access. Am I missing something silly?

Comment: can you access the same from windows explorer? in a seperate module just try to open the file writing explicitly "set x = workbooks.open("abcd\xyz.xls")"

Comment: @mrc Yes I can. When I right click on the folder, there is a button under permissions that says 'read-only'. When I try to make this folder not 'read-only' it just defaults back...The file inside of the folder is not read only though... don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: @mrc When I bring the file to my desktop, I can open it. It must be a network thing...